# Filter tags by tags and count

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel

My mysql structure is as follows:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| id | title/text/moretext/img | language_id | course_id | country_code |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | Plenty of information   |           1 |         3 | it           |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

I'm using the laravel framework to build my site.

This is a recipe. It is an appetiser (course_id 3 translates to appetiser using php arrays since page is multilingual).
This appetiser is from it. 'it' translates to Italy, again in PHP since the country names will be multilingual.
The recipe is written in English (language_id is a one to many relationship to a languages table, language id 1 is English).
This information is given in case it changes anything, which I doubt, but it's better to play it safe.

Each article will have only one of each of these tags.

What I need is a select list echoing all available options (options relating to filters in use, so if I have no recipes from South-Africa in French, South-Africa won't show in the filter list if French is the selected language).

Google yielded nothing, and I'm running out of time and my ideas are at zero. Is there any way to implement this with ease?

I've looked into http://luis-almeida.github.com/filtrify/ and think it would be exactly what I want in functionality, but I think it would be way too heavy on a large database as I'd have to query the entire database and make a list out of that. But I might be wrong.

An implementation using something like http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ would also be possible for selections, but I don't know how to even implement it for this.

Any help would be truly fantastic. I'm way over my head here and am all out of programming passion. I've spent a couple of days on this already and am drawing a blank. None else to ask.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to get past this (you can always come back and enhance it later) would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_code, language_id 
FROM recipes 
ORDER BY country_code, language_id
```

with whatever joins/translations are necessary to get country names and language names, then make a single dropdown from the result...

```
Deutschland - Deutsch 
France - Francais 
South Africa - Afrikaans 
South Africa - English 
United States - English
```

So each item is both the country name and the language.  If most countries have only one or two languages spoken, this shouldn't be overwhelming to the user.